# Display binary image data in image

Tags: javascript, html, image, binary-data

I can't figure out how to display image bytes returned from a web api in an html Image. This is how the data looks in firefox console (truncated for brevity):

```
������JFIF�������������C����������������������...
```

I've tried to use `data:image/jpeg;base64, " + btoa(data)` as image src, I get `String contains an invalid character` error. When I use `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)))`instead of `btoa` I get no errors, but the image is not displayed. The Content-Type of the response is `image/jpeg`.

The image is rendered correctly in Fiddler.

Any ideas how to get the image to display the data?

Comment: can you share Fiddler link?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. The problem was that I used Jquery `$.ajax` to get the image data. Jquery automatically converted the received bytes into an UTF-16 string and passed that string into the `success` callback.

If I used basic `XMLHttpRequest` I was able to render the received image in html, like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");    
xhr.onload = function() {
  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
  var base64Data = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, byteArray));
  image.attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64, " + base64Data);
};
xhr.send(jsonPayload);
```